# Ruby TimeZone Milliseconds Since Epoch At Midnight

Tags: ruby, datetime, timezone

I need to get the time in milliseconds since 1970 for today with BST (british summer time) offset

```
a = DateTime.now
=> Fri, 29 Sep 2017 16:30:29 +0100

b = DateTime.new(a.year, a.month, a.day, 0, 0, 0, 0)
=> Fri, 29 Sep 2017 00:00:00 +0000   # this is an hour out  

b.strftime('%Q').to_i
1506643200000                        # therefore this is an hour out
```

How do I correct this?

```
b = b.in_time_zone
=> Fri, 29 Sep 2017 01:00:00 BST +01:00  # looks promising but...

b.strftime('%Q').to_i
=> 0                                     # grrr
```

Any help most welcome

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
a = DateTime.now
=> Fri, 29 Sep 2017 16:30:29 +0100

a = a.beginning_of_day
=> Fri, 29 Sep 2017 00:00:00 +0100

milliseconds_since_1970 = a.to_i * 1000
=> 1506639600000                     <-- correct!
```